# download the pod dependency based on input iOS

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c, cocoapods

How to control the dependency POD install in programmatically, for example we are developing one pod that pod has more than one dependency pod, we no need to download or install all dependency pod, we have to install or download dependency pod according to user input
Is it possible ?
If is possible, how we will achieve this ?

Use case : I'm developing one pod that has 4 dependency, In the pod spec file I have mention the dependency. in this 4 dependencies no need to download / install all. I want to install only based one user input like, the user want only 2 (dependency 1, dependency 4) then we no need to download or  install all the dependency.

Comment: You have like 4 subpecs then? So each of the subpecs have its own dependencies, no? Cocoapods download them all?

Comment: Thanks, got it we have subspec in pod https://guides.cocoapods.org/syntax/podspec.html#subspec